# I want to disable the wifi hardware key on my laptop, it keeps fluctuating on/off on its own. I want it to be always on

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint

My wifi hardware switch keeps switching on and off without me doing anything every 5 minutes or so. Is there anything I can do about this frustrating problem? My idea is to somehow disable the switch, but I don't know how to do it.

I use Linux Mint as my primary operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the switch works on a level below the OS, so there's not anything you can do within the OS itself.  That being said, check your BIOS setup, often you can set it so that the switch does not control the hardware (I had a system with a similar issue a while back.)

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm

Comment: No problem, happy to help!